# Android application in tablets or phones wants to post message generated by user to user wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

I am developing an Android application to run on Android tablets and phones.  I want to add a feature for the user to post to his wall text selected from my application.

I can do that now.  However, the postings to my ser apear under my developer name via my app (which the user would not want my name but his/hers).  I want the user name via my app or just Posted by my app to appear on the user's Facebook wall.

I cannot find a way to do this.  My app interfaces with Facebook via:
Website with Facebook Login

All that I want is for my user to post a message from my app.  An example would be if my app were a game would be to post the score on his wall (certainly without my name).

I am an Android developer and not a Facebook developer.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/ is probably a good starting point for a beginner